# Makefile Bash Error, Cannot Change Directories

Tags: linux, makefile, rhel

I have the following section in a Makefile:

```
build-ui:
    @echo "\nInstalling front-end dependencies..."
    cd ${ROOT_DIR}/app \
    && npm install \
    && npm run build
```

However, when it runs (sudo make build-ui), I get:

```
\nInstalling front-end dependencies...
cd /home/ec2-user/meta-system/app \
&& npm install \
&& npm run build
/bin/sh: line 2: npm: command not found
make: *** [Makefile:73: build-ui] Error 127
```

Yet, if I manually enter the command `cd /home/ec2-user/meta-system/app`, it works just fine (along with `npm install` and `npm run build`).  Thoughts on what I have coded wrong in the Makefile that it does not work through a `make` call but I can execute the individual steps manually?

Comment: It seems that you don't have `npm` in your `$PATH` inside your `su` environment. The reason "if I manually enter...it works fine" is because you are not using `su`. Consider whether you really need to do `sudo make build-ui`, or `make build-ui` without `su` is good enough. If you really need `sudo make build-ui`, you need to make sure that `sudo npm` can find the `npm` executable.